# woocommerce doesn't show some products' description

Tags: woocommerce

I'm building an e-commerce with woocommerce and wordpress and everything is fine, but Today I discovered that there are some products where the description is not shown.
it's not a matter of conflicts or theme, I already made a full conflict test and nothing resolved.

an example of this issue:
https://tattoomarket.it/prodotto/adattatore-ad-angolo-rca/

an example of a product without this issue:
https://tattoomarket.it/prodotto/clip-cord-cavo-alimentazione-schuko/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using elemento? Because it seems that "element" has his properties set to " display none".
**Removing/changing that css element fixed the issue.**

[image]

This is how it looked after changing it.

[image]

***You can fix it just changing that propertie. An example.***

```
elemento {
    display: block;
}
```

You could also use this... it works for me.

```
#tab-description {
    display: block !important;
}
```

But I would say that the best option is to changing it using the interface of Elemento.

Comment: yes I use elementor, but I never touched the single product page with elementor I have no idea of what makes ths style:display:none

Comment: @EnricoScuderi Maybe a custom code in a page, maybe someone else put that property by accident when inserting that option. Because I can't see the code in your side or you have not provided any is hard to tell. But now that you know the cause, you can fix it.

Comment: that's exactly what I need!!! do you have any suggestion about how can I fix it permanently?? maybe a css code...

Comment: I just edited my answer, test it and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: just tried, but it didn't work...

Comment: Where did you put the code? how it looks? Please provide more info so we can help.

Comment: You could use display: block; !important (but honestly is not recomended... it's a quick solution though...

Comment: I putted the css code in the custom css section; I already made it some times for other codes and it worked

Comment: @EnricoScuderi I just added a new alternative. Try it.

Comment: yes it work... I'm so grateful, you're my savior <3<3<3<3

Comment: if my answer helped you, you can mark my answer.

Comment: done :) thank you